# Retain previous data frame based on condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe

So I'm trying to update or retain a dataframe `df2` based on a certain condition of another data frame `df1`.

For Example, Assuming `df1` get updated for every 30 seconds, so **if the number of rows** in `df1` i.e  `nrow(df1)!= 0` then `df2 <-  df1` else if retain the previous values in `df2`.

NOTE: On the first iteration, `df2` can be initialized to a `NULL` dataframe.

Following is my code

```
#Initializing df2 as empty dataframe
df2 <- data.frame(weight = integer(),stringAsFactors = FALSE) 

#Condition to check if number of rows in df1 != 0
if(nrow(df1) != 0){

     df2 <- df1
     temp <- df1 #Another copy of df1
}

else{

   df2 <- temp
}
```

Here I created an another data frame called `temp` to keep a copy of `df1` so that it can be used when `nrow(df1) == 0`. I don't know if the usage of `temp` is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

This code will create an empty dataframe named `df2`. If `nrow(df1)>0` then it will effectively assign the contents of `df1` to `df2`. If `nrow(df1)==0` then `df2` remains empty.

```
df2 <- data.frame()
if(nrow(df1)>0) df2 <- df1
```

I have a hard time imagining why this is useful. If, perhaps, you intended to "grow" `df2` by appending on whatever is in `df1` - which might be more common - then do something like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame()
if(nrow(df1)>0) df2 <- rbind(df2, df1)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am trying to build a shiny application where I will be using data from `df1` to analyze but I will be analyzing only if I get a new data in `df1` else I will be using previous values in `df1` to analyze. Hence my question was regarding updating the second dataframe `df2` only if new values are updated in the first data frame `df1`.